# Не открывается другой виджет

Tags: qt, qwidget

У меня есть виджет TeacherWidget, у него есть

```
signals:
   void addTest();
public slots:
   void addTestClicked();
```

В конструткоре я  делаю:

```
 connect(mAddTestButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(addTestClicked()));
```

и в  кликет:

```
void TeacherWidget::addTestClicked()
{
    emit addTest();
    close();
}
```

Когда я  жму на кнопку чтобы  открыть  другой  виджет он не октрывается.
Другой виджет:

```
signals:
    void addTestEnter();
public slots:
    void addTestEnterClicked();

void AddTestWidget::addTestEnterClicked()
{
    emit addTestEnter();
    close();
}
```

И в  главном виджете  делаю:

```
private slots:
   void addTest();
   void addTestEnter();

void StudyTests::addTest()
{
    AddTestWidget addTestWidget;
    connect(&addTestWidget, SIGNAL(addTestEnter()), this, SLOT(addTestEnter()));
    addTestWidget.show();
} 

void StudyTests::addTestEnter()
{
    mAddTestWidget = new AddTestWidget();
    mAddTestWidget->show();
    mMainWidget->close();
}
```

И что  не так я не пойму

Answer (score 0):

```
void StudyTests::addTest()
{
    AddTestWidget addTestWidget;
    connect(&addTestWidget, SIGNAL(addTestEnter()), this, SLOT(addTestEnter()));
    addTestWidget.show();
}
```

Замените на:

```
void StudyTests::addTest()
{
    AddTestWidget  *addTestWidget = new AddTestWidget (this);
    addTestWidget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    connect(addTestWidget, SIGNAL(addTestEnter()), this, SLOT(addTestEnter()));
    addTestWidget->show();
}
```

В Вашем варианте виджет создает и разрушается, как только заканчивается выполнение функции `addTest`, по-этому Вы ничего и не видите.